# Handle back navigation button on mobile

Tags: angular, nativescript

In my mobile application, I have this login page and once the user enters his credentials, he gets to the homepage. When I tap on the back button, I get back on the login page. But I'd like the back button to work like when I use Facebook : when I tap on the back button, I get back on the homepage or at least the previous activity I was doing. Is this possible to implement that in Nativescript/Angular project ?

Thank you

Comment: I think this will help you.

https://github.com/gabesumner/nativescript-docs/blob/master/navigation.md

Answer (score 1):

When you forward the user to the homepage use

```
_router.navigateByUrl('/homepageUrl', true);
```

or

```
_router.navigateByInstruction(router.generate(['/Homepage']), true);
```

`skipLocationChange: true` then the login page Url should

Not tested myself but I think this is what you want.

Comment: This doesn't help. He needs to catch the event of back button. I'm searching for it too.

Comment: No idea what you mean. If the redirect to the login page is not added to the history (`skipLocationChange: true`), then the back button will lead to the page the user was before the login dialog appeard

Comment: I was facing problems with back button and I just wanted to get the event, so I though the person who asked wanted the same. But maybe your answer is enough. Just in my case doesn't fix. But for the title of the question I thought he was asking for it. Forget it ^^